# How can someone evaluate llama index model?

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface, openai-gym, chatbot

I have built a openAI llama index based model which takes multiple pdf and able to give chatbot based response. I want to evaluate the llm for accuracy. I already know method such as Rouge and Bleu. Is there any other way to evaluate model ?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any other way to evaluate model ?

Assuming you have a test set with gold answers, you can use a text generation metric. See [Evaluation of Text Generation: A Survey](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.14799). Typical metrics: [TF-IDF cosine](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/120901/843), [Rouge](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47045436/395857), Bleu, BertScore, Sentence-Bert, and more recently, [GPTScore](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2302.04166.pdf) and [G-Eval](https://arxiv.org/abs/2303.16634). Note that they have some serious limitations when evaluating GPT output {1,2}.

---

More recent works:

- JudgeLM: Fine-tuned Large Language Models are Scalable Judges. Code: https://github.com/baaivision/JudgeLM. Paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/2310.17631

---

References:

- {1} Goyal, Tanya, Junyi Jessy Li, and Greg Durrett. "[News Summarization and Evaluation in the Era of GPT-3.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2209.12356.pdf)" arXiv preprint arXiv:2209.12356 (2022).
- {2} Tianyi Zhang, Faisal Ladhak, Esin Durmus, Percy Liang, Kathleen McKeown, Tatsunori B. Hashimoto. [Benchmarking Large Language Models for News Summarization](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2301.13848.pdf). arXiv:2301.13848.

---

Since comparing the semantic similarity of the predicted answer with a reference question has some limitations, one may look at complementing the analysis with a human evaluation. The following papers survey criteria used for human evaluation of generated texts (thanks Mengjiao Zhang for pointing me to refs {3,4}):

- {3} [A Survey of Evaluation Metrics Used for NLG Systems](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2008.12009.pdf)
- {4} [Perturbation CheckLists for Evaluating NLG Evaluation Metrics](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2109.05771.pdf) (unfortunately, they forgot about QA)

From {3}:

[image]